# Exponential Function - proof of continuity at $x=0$

Tags: analysis

How do you prove that the exponential function is continuous at $x=0$ and how do you prove it is continuous for all real $x$?

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the answers to your question about subgroups, if any of them was clear to you.

Comment: It depends on your definition of the exponential function. (There are several reasonable definitions.)

Comment: Is there a particular difficulty you're having in answering this question? Are you having trouble with the delta-epsilon definition?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\exp x$ is continuous at $x=0$. This means that $$\lim_{h\to 0}e^{h}=1$$

Now, consider any other $x$. Then $$e^x\cdot\lim_{h\to 0}e^{h}=e^x\\\lim_{h\to 0}e^x\cdot e^{h}=e^x\\ \lim_{h\to 0}e^{x+h}=e^x$$

which says this is continuous at every other point. The same idea works in showing it is differentiable at every point as soon as it is differentiable at the origin. Now, it depends on how you define it to devise a proof of continuity and/or differentiability at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that  the exponential function is differntiable on $\mathbb{R}$, 
$$(\exp)'(x)=\exp(x),\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R},$$
then it's continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ as well.

Comment: The downvote is strange. One can of course define $\exp$ as the unique solution to $$\begin{cases}y'=y\\y(0)=1\end{cases}$$